# .NET StringBuilder and verbatim string literal

Tags: c#, stringbuilder, verbatim-string

In my Application there is a class that works with **PdfSharp** to generate some PDF reports. I specified output folder as a string with verbatim

```
string file_path = @"D:\Intranet\Students\DailyMarks\";
```

Also there is a StringBuilder that generates file name based on some ID and DateTime:

```
... sb.Append(document.Type); sb.Append(document.Id); sb.Append(DateTime.Now.ToShortString());
```

And finally I do the following

```
file_path + sb.toString();
```

But my Application cathes an exception. After debugging session I see that actually my **file_path** is

```
file_path = "D:\\Intranet\\Students\\DailyMarks\\...";
```

As I understand it happens after concatenation of origin file with StringBuilder's toString() call. 
I tried to replace **file_path** string with something like this:

```
file_path = file_path.Replace(@"\\",@"\");
```

but it doesn't work. Where did I do wrong?

Comment: Could you post the full file path?

Comment: @AlexFilipovici, if it will be helpful then here it is: "D:\\Intranet\\Students\\DailyMarks\\ECON_BSC2351_3:09AM.pdf

Comment: "After debugging session I see that actually my file_path is 
file_path = "D:\\Intranet\\Students\\DailyMarks\\..." - That's just the way the debugger shows the strings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably this is caused by the `DateTime.Now.ToShortString()` method, which adds forbidden characters to the path (`:`).

Comment: My great thanks. You were absolutely right about forbidden characters ( : )

Answer (score 3):

It's totally fine.

```
"D:\\Intranet\\Students\\DailyMarks\\..." == @"D:\Intranet\Students\DailyMarks\..."
```

In regular string you need to escape slashes, in verbatim it's done automatically

Answer (score 0):

Another similar situation I faced today was about sending Japanese 「：」 (colon with whole inside) as a file's name's element and it worked. I wonder, why Russian colon calls an exception and Japanese not. Very interesting.